# Malsup ajax form does not work on mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, ajaxform

I have a responsive website and I'm using http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ ajaxForm to submit forms via ajax. It supports file upload. It works like a charm but when I try to upload a file (even 50kb file) from my Android/iOs, I get a "could not process previous request. low memory" type of message. File upload works perfectly on my desktop. I've tested from many mobile phones and I get the same error message. What's wrong?

Comment: Did you every figure this out?